# "ts.getDecorators is not a function" error while running ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store AppState --root --module app.module.ts

Tags: ngrx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcS14.png)
This is my error, while running the command

i am expecting to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Probably the version of the `@ngrx/schematics` is different from the version of `@ngrx/store`, you can check it in `package.json` file of your project.

If they are different, - copy `@ngrx/store` version to `@ngrx/schematics` version by hand and run `npm install`.

BTW, check if this lines exist in the file angular.json:

```
"cli": {
  "schematicCollections": [
    "@ngrx/schematics"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved me when I change the ngrx version same as angular version in package.json then *npm i*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).